# Como fazer a conta em % de largura de div's de um site responsivo

Tags: css

Gostaria de saber como eu faço aquela conta que pega a largura de um site e divide por um valor x pra chegar no resultado adequado de um site responsivo

Comment: Site responsivo não usa calculo algum, ele usa `@media` com (min-width) ou (max-width) para ajustar para cada resolução. Creio que você deva ter se confundido com outra coisa.

Comment: mais tipo, eu uso o `@media screen and (max-width: 480px)` e eu estou acessando o site de um desktop, ai eu vou diminuindo a tela, ai o site vai ficando desconfigurado até chegar no `480px`, eu eu reparo que em alguns sites a gente diminui a tela e o conteudo se adequa para qualquer tamanho, isso que eu queria saber entendeu? um exemplo pra você é o youtube, vai diminuindo a tela ai e ve como ele se comporta

Comment: Acho que você esta se confundindo em algo, uma coisa é ajustar o tamanho baseado em porcentagem (como `display: flex` por exemplo), aonde os elementos continuam no mesmo lugar, outra coisa é site se ajustar pra uma necessidade, mudando os menus, tornando as coisas mais fáceis para telas menores, isso seria o responsivo.

Comment: não intendi sua resposta e creio que você não entendeu minha dúvida

Comment: Não é questão de entender a duvida, a questão é que talvez vc nem saiba o que é responsividade, você pode achar que funciona de maneira, mas é apenas uma percepção sua, na verdade é bem provavel que seja uma série de media-querys, uma a cada tamanho de tela.

Comment: ta legal, vou pesquisar mais sobre o assunto, não acho legal encher o `CSS` de media-querys

Comment: então é porque você não entende CSS ... css não é uma linguagem de marcação ou de programação, ele é um "estilo cascata", (inclusive CSS significa estilo cascata mesmo), a organização só vem com a experiencia, eu trabalho com HTML e CSS desde 2008 e mesmo assim até hoje é dificil organizar um CSS que crio do zero.

Comment: mais é normal então cada div ter até 10 linhas de código? ou eu que sou muito novato na area, porque meu `CSS`misericordia em

Comment: Mayron, não é bem assim, não é questão de normalidade e nem sempre funciona assim, não tem um esquema padrão unico que você vai conseguir aprender/dominar em 6 meses, como eu mesmo disse, eu trabalho com CSS e HTML desde 2008, organizar isto não é fácil, por isso tanta gente apela para Frameworks como Bootstrap. Para se criar algo proprio e ainda conseguir uma boa organização é necessário muito experiencia, deu pra entender, não tem formula mágica e não tem uma maneira unica de se fazer as coisas. Você pode conseguir um mesmo "efeito" de formas diferentes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Layout fluido:** é a técnica de codificar um layout de forma que seus componentes se encolha conforme o viewport(janela do browser) vai diminuindo. 
A base principal do layout fluido é usar [medidas relativas](http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/css/unidades-css-rem-vh-vw-vmin-vmax-ex-ch/), que fazem um elemento se ajustar a qualquer tamanho de tela. [Leia mais](https://www.turbosite.com.br/blog/layout-fluido-ou-responsivo/)

**Layout responsivo:** é técnica de adaptar o layout pra qualquer tipo de resolução, em que um usuário possa acessar. Ele utiliza o **layout fluido** como base. O design responsivo usa as [medias queries](http://sergiolopes.org/media-queries-conteudo/) para adaptar(melhorar a experiencia do usuário naquela resolução) o seu layout conforme ele quebra em uma determina resolução. [Leia mais](https://moip.com.br/blog/design-responsivo-por-que-voce-precisa-saber/)

Para converter pixels em %, bastar usar essa formula: **objeto / contexto = resultado x 100**

Um exemplo: Supondo que tenho div pai de 1200px e a div filha tem 250px, então eu pego o **objeto(div filha) e divido pelo contexto(div pai), e multiplico por 100**.

250px(objeto) / 1200(contexto) * 100 = 20.8333333333%.

Answer (score 2):

Creio que não exista calculo algum, existem muitas técnicas para diferentes coisas, sites responsivos geralmente usam um media-query para cada tamanho, por exemplo, o bootstrap usa os seguintes tamanhos para os grids (na versão 3):

### Telas pequenas de celular:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    /*aplica as necessidade conforme necessário */
}
```

### Telas pequenas de tablet:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /*aplica as necessidade conforme necessário */
}
```

### Telas de tamanho médio (desktop provavelmente):

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    /*aplica as necessidade conforme necessário */
}
```

### Telas de tamanho grande:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    /*aplica as necessidade conforme necessário */
}
```

Em outras palavras, você pode usar multiplos media-queries para cada tamanho e necessidade.

CSS é um documento de *"estilo cascata"*, ou seja, fora algumas exceções como diferentes seletores ou o uso do `!import`, os seletores abaixo geralmente vão sobrescrevendo os valores anteriores que combinam com os mesmos elementos. Então em CSS é normal usar várias vezes algo, como um media-query para cada tamanho.