# Sistema de grid, calculos

Tags: css, bootstrap-3

Antes de eu iniciar minha pergunta, quero deixar claro, já vi alguns tópicos relacionados.

[Este é um deles](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244512/como-fazer-a-conta-em-de-largura-de-divs-de-um-site-responsivo/244519#244519), onde Guilherme Nascimento explica como funciona `media queries`, e a resposta que foi aceita na pergunta já explica como fazer o calculo, mas tem um porém...

Seguindo as dicas da resposta aceita, eu tentei mas não consegui, no **Bootstrap** tem a `col-md-5`, tentei chegar nesse resultado:

```
.col-md-5   { width: 41.66666667%; }
```

Mas não consegui, como foi feito o calculo da coluna de grid `MD` do **Bootstrap**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O padrão do bootstrap é dividir o layout em 12 colunas de tamanhos iguais. Nesse caso, o 5 no nome da classe indica que o elemento deve ocupar 5 colunas, ou seja 5/12 que equivale a 41.66667%.

Comment: 5/12*100 correto? deu esse resultado mesmo. Muito simples e eu fazendo: 992/1200*100